# How to swap sides of 2 elements (one with float:left, the other is with float:right)

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a website with an image on one side, and text on the other. 
This is how it looks: 
[image]

As you see in the image - there is some text on the left and image on the right. 
Then you have an image on the left and text to the right,(in rotation) ect..

This is a simple example I made using jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fyawuuh1/1/

When displaying the page on a mobile - (using @media queries) I want to organize the image to be always on top, and under the image to have text (no rotation), That means that I'll have:

- Image
- Text
- Image
- Text
- Image
- Text

I am having difficulties finding a way getting it look like this.`.` 
[image]

Comment: Don't float the text blocks. Only float the images. Put each right floating image before its text block in the HTML. Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides changing the html structure u can use `flexbox` to achieve it with css:

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
#divA {
  order: 2;
}
#divB {
   order: 1;
}
```

Comment: I think this works ! :O 
Testing this again. (Why the hell did someone vote you down :X )

Comment: Wrote this pretty fast might be some problem i am not aware of.Well keep in mind that flexbox is not supported on older ie browsers http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: I believe so u can see the details in the links about which versions

Comment: Well images don't appear on safari for some reason. I'll maybe give it display: block; or something. 
I voted you up. 
You solved my problem. Thanks A LOT!

Comment: I cant see the image on my mobile - Do you know how to solve this maybe? 
(I gave it a `displey:block;` property. doesn't work.. )

Comment: Unfortunately i haven't tested it much on different browsers, i can only guess that it is not supported on that specific version as i said the browser support is sketchy at times...