# Why the image isn't displayed on safari when using display:flex; & flex-flow:colum; and use oreder:1/2; on child-elements?

Tags: css, responsive-design, mobile-safari, flexbox

This continues my older post: [How to swap sides of 2 elements (one with float:left, the other is with float:right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728315/how-to-swap-sides-of-2-elements-one-with-floatleft-the-other-is-with-floatri/29728466?noredirect=1#comment47591665_29728466)

I think you should read it because the structure of my page is well explaned there. (and the answer too. I promise it's not long).

I used:

```
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
```

on a container div, and gave it's 2 child-elements (one image, the other is a div):

```
    order: 2;
```

and

```
    order: 1;
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fyawuuh1/6/

The thing is - on iPhones the images aren't displayed.

Is there any simple solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.page-wrap {
  display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
 }
```

Reference taken from [here](https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/)

Comment: I added this to the CSS and it's not working. 
I'm sure it's this because when I open the page on the chrome dev-tools, I disable the "`display:flex;`" and get the exact same view like the one on the mobile.

Comment: You've found the cause then, easy fix :)

Comment: Yes, So how to apply the fix. this is my css: 

`.part2 .container{
    /*min-height: 6.5em;
    height: inherit;*/
    margin-bottom: 7em;
    width: 100%;

  display: flex;
  display:-webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display:-moz-flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column;
  flex-flow: column;

    /*position: relative;*/
   }`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you may have some cross browser issues. You may be able to resolve about all of these. For your `flex` layout systems, be sure you are still vendor prefixing these, specifically `-wekbit` for using Chrome and Safari broswers

Example

```
display: -wekbit-flex;
-webkit-flex-flow: column;
-webkit-order: 2;
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/L1gf3hxz/) - with `-wekbit` prefixes

Comment: I added this to the CSS and it's not working. 
I'm sure it's this because when I open the page on the chrome dev-tools, I disable the "`display:flex;`" and get the exact same view like the one on the mobile.