# How do I swap between HTML tags (inside and outside of div tags)? Can I work in my case with display:flex;?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a website that I'm trying to make responsive. 
Some `div`s have to change places as mentioned in my older post: [How to swap sides of 2 elements (one with float:left, the other is with float:right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728315/how-to-swap-sides-of-2-elements-one-with-floatleft-the-other-is-with-floatri)

But this time it's much more complex.

This is how the page looks:

On the left div: an image.

On the right div: baner of the client, "the challange", some text, "out results", some text. "read more" link. 
(right after it there is the same structure just with the image on the right and text on the left - using float on the divs). 
[image]

And this is how it should look on a mobile:
First comes the banner - then the image - then the rest of the text.
[image]

This is my HTML structure:

```
<div class="cs"> 
    <div class="leftDiv">
        <img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen-child/images/big-image.png">
    </div>
    <div class="rightDiv">
        <a href="http://www.example.com/clients/theClientsName-case-study/">
            <img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen-child/images/banner.png" class="mini-logo-l">
        </a>
        <h1>The <span class="babyblue">Challenge</span></h1>
        <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text . </p>
        <h1>Our <span class="babyblue">Results</span></h1>
        <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text .</p>
        <p class="read-more text-yellow"><a href="http://www.example.com/clients/theClientsName-case-study/">Read more</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you notice, the tags are inside tags on the desktop version, which is ok. 
But when looking on the page on a mobile - a lot of tags inside the "left" and "right" divs have to swap places.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uh8L0g4t/

Comment: To make things easier, why don't you copy the code for the banner and place it at the top. Then, make it appear / disappear (i.e. 'swap') using CSS media queries? Every other element can be a block without float so they're arranged from top-down. The banner image is only 1 line long and it can probably save you lots of code if you try to actually move it.

Comment: I know how to do this, I just want to learn more hardcore CSS :ם

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ecanc3c/) for what I described in the comments. I've used !important because you are unnecessarily increasing the priority of the elements so I'm a bit lazy to clone them to gain the priority for the elements in mobile view.

```
.desktop{
    display:block;
}
.mobile{
    display:none;
}
@media screen and (max-width:600px){
.desktop{
    display:none;
}
.mobile{
    display:block;
}
}
```

And for your HTML

```
<div class="left">
     <img class="mobile" ... />
</div>
<div class="right">
     <img class="desktop" ... />
</div>
```

It's the most 'elegant' way for your case. If you try to move things around without cloning the image, you will end up either using more code, or high chance of breaking something else.